# Is there a way to add a user to all BIM360/ACC projects, or remove them from all via Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I see individual endpoints to add/remove a user in the public documentation; these endpoints need to be called project-by-project (requiring many API calls), so I thought someone may know a better way to approach this.

If there is a way to 'add-to-all-projects' or 'remove-from-all-projects' via simpler/fewer API calls, that would save a great deal of time. This will be run against 500-1000 projects in ACC/BIM 360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a single endpoint to 'add-to-all-projects' or 'remove-from-all-projects', add a user to multiple projects requires to call the endpoint(https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/) for each project, while removing a user from ACC\BIM360 project is still not released, but will be coming soon.